# Can I solve the problem in machine learning where you don't have idea where issue is coming from?

Tags: machine-learning

I have the telecom customers data and there is another team who writes scripts which handles the customer's requirement.

When Someone messes up the script the issues will be reflected in the customer data and I do not have access to the scripts.

When a customer makes changes to his/her services probably he may end up paying more, less or as expected for his/her services. There is no way to tell that how script messed it up or which script messed it up or which parameters has effected. Until you manually debug after reporting the issue.

Is it possible for me just using customers data, will I be able to predict that this customer has an issue or not based on the past issues customers have faced and which parameters has affected the issue before reporting the issue?

Every time someone messes up the script there will be a new issue and new parameters. Once the issue is fixed you will not see those recurring issues.

if yes how and if no why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use anomaly detection for this. All you need is a set of examples without any error for training the model. Once you are done with it, you can check the anomalies by using the model. You can use either Gaussian distribution or multivariate Gaussian distribution.